# Increase gap between two point labels in line chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

I have integrated a line chart in my project using `Charts` library and have been using it for a while now. It was working fine with few data points, however as the number of data have been increased since then the point labels (x-axis) are overlapping with each other. Is there a way to display the data-point labels without getting overlapped?

[image: Line Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find how to increase the gap between two labels on x-axis (top) however I have managed to improve the issue a little by displaying them vertically so that they are at-least visible on chart.

```
lineChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 270
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue using `labelCount` property. also, you can set using `setLabelCount` property, I hope this helps you.

```
xAxis.labelCount = 5
xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: true)
```

See this post for more info: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1969

Comment: The labels are getting separated but the data points are not showing properly like there are 5 labels on x-axis and there are more than 5 data points plotted on the chart. Can we also show the data points plotted equivalent with the number of labels displayed?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh  you are  near to the solution keep experimenting solve the problem